# Use of jQuery.fn.data('events') is deprecated

Tags: jquery

I'm trying upgrade jQuery from 1.4 to 1.9.

What API should I use equivalent to data('events')?

Comment: What are you doing with `data('events')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them in `$._data(element).events`

It returns an object with keys being event names and values being arrays of objects for each listener

```js
var $div = $('#test').click(function(){
  console.log('clicked')
});

console.log($._data($div[0]).events)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
test
</div>
```

[Fiddle for version 3.3.1](https://jsfiddle.net/axe8vpbz/)