# Find out which delegated events are attached to a collection of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events

I have some jQuery code that repeatedly attaches delegated handlers (e.g. `click()`) to an element, so that when the event is triggered, the handler gets called several times.

I do know the strategic solution: in my scenario, the delegate should be the only child of the AJAX-loaded code container, so that any replacement will wipe out, together with the DOM elements, any handlers they might have delegated.

Another possibility would be to rewrite such assignments as

```
$(...).off(event, selector).on(event, selector, event => { });
```

to ensure that no double delegation ever happens.

What I'd like is a tactical solution to warn myself and the other project developers when they have inadvertently added (or left in place, since this is a major re-engineering and code cleanup project) any delegated handlers to objects higher in the DOM tree than the chosen container. My idea is:

```
+++ let before = app.developer.calculateHandlerSyndrome($('#container'));
performObjectLoad('#container', whatever)
   .then(...)
+++   .then(_ => {
+++       if (before !== app.developer.calculateHandlerSyndrome($('#container'))) {
+++           sys.error("The object " + whatever + " has over-delegated");
+++       }
+++   });
```

For my `calculateHandlerSyndrome($selector)`, I'm thinking of returning an array of selectors, starting from the specified one and working upwards recursively through all the parents until I hit `document`. To compare the arrays I'll just `JSON.stringify()` them.

What I lack is a method to retrieve the event handlers for a given selector, since the `$.data('events')` method appears not to be working.

I *have* found the events I need inside a property of each DOM element called "jQuery1234(ALARGENUMBER)56789", but it's obvious that the number is a unique ID and will change at each page load. I *could* check *all* properties of *each* element and find whether there's one called jQuery*something*, but it's too kludgy a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jQuery.fn.data('events')` interface is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47421019/use-of-jquery-fn-dataevents-is-deprecated) and has been replaced by `$._data(element).events`.

So the approach would be:

```
function handlerSyndrome($selector) {
    let parent   = $selector.parent(), syndrome = [ ];
    if (parent.length) {
        syndrome = handlerSyndrome(parent);
    }
    // Get the element's handlers
    let ev = $._data($selector[0]).events;
    // Transform it to an object with count: { click: 7, blur: 2 }, ...
    let hnd = { };
    for (const h in ev) {
        hnd[h] = ev[h].length;
    }
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(hnd).length) {
        syndrome.push(hnd);
    }
    return syndrome;
}
```

This will take a jQuery selector such as `$('#container')` and return something like,

```
[
  {
    "click": 20,
    "focusout": 1,
    "focusin": 1,
    "keydown": 2,
    "keyup": 1,
    "mouseup": 1,
    "mousedown": 1,
    "change": 2
  },
  {
    "click": 1
  }
]
```

and will allow checking whether the parent tree above that selector got anything added to its handlers. It will not check for **changes** or **rearrangements**.

It might be necessary to delay the call to check after the load using `window.setTimeout()`.